# Структура папок на многостраничном сайте

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, какую для вас наиболее удобную структуру папок вы использовали для многостраничных сайтов. Появилась необходимость не хранить все стили в одном файле и разбить на компоненты, как это лучше сделать чтобы и другим разработчикам было более понятно?

Answer (score 3):

В каждом проекте своя файловая структура, используйте такую, какая вам нравится, но старайтесь раскладывать файлы по папкам логично и давать им логичное название. Например, в проектах на React все файлы проекта складывают в `src` директорию, а внутри неё есть `assets` (для статики, шрифты, статические картинки и т.д), кроме этого часто делают папку `components` (естественно для компонентов), `helpers` (для утилит), `api` (для файлов взаимодействия с API) и многие другие. Всё зависит от выбранный технологий и конкретного проекта. Если в выбранной технологии есть какие-то "хорошие практики", то используйте их.